# SetSimpleColumn not aligning after 10th line

Tags: itext

I am using the iTextSharp assembly version 5.5.10 and think to face a bug. When I position my SetSimpleColumns for some unknown reason the 11th till the 14t column remain on the same line.
I first thought it was related to margins, but my rectangles with the same coordinates position correct.

This is how the result looks like:

[image: position example]

The code is as follow:

```
Dim iADsPerPage As Integer = 14
Dim iRow As Integer = 0
dBottom = 760 'Next Line (one line = 15)

For Each oRow As DataRow In dtADs.Rows
    iRow = iRow + 1
    dBottom = dBottom - 43.6 'Next Line (one line = 15)

    myText = New Phrase(oRow("BulletinReference").ToString, oFont)
    dLeftSide = 102.0
    dCellSize = 106.0
    ct.SetSimpleColumn(myText, dLeftSide, dBottom + dFontLine, dLeftSide + dCellSize, dCellSize, 0, Element.ALIGN_CENTER)
    ct.Go()

    myText = New Phrase(Left(oRow("BulletinReference").ToString, 40), oFont)
    dLeftSide = 210.0
    dCellSize = 302.0
    cb.Rectangle(dLeftSide, dBottom, dCellSize, dCellHeight)
    cb.Stroke()
    Response.Write(">" & " " & dLeftSide & " " & dBottom + dFontLine & " " & dLeftSide + dCellSize & " " & dCellSize & "<<br>")
    ct.SetSimpleColumn(myText, dLeftSide, dBottom + dFontLine, dLeftSide + dCellSize, dCellSize, 0, Element.ALIGN_LEFT)
    ct.Go()

    If iRow = 11 Then 'force position as test
        myText = New Phrase("hello world!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!", oFont)
        ct.SetSimpleColumn(myText, 210, 100, 210 + 302, 302, 0, Element.ALIGN_LEFT)
        ct.Go()
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot reproduce that behavior. There might be something fishy about the contents of your data rows. You do not check the result of the `ct.Go()` calls, maybe some content could not be set properly.

Comment: I was expecting that too, but check the hello world example. Also that one is placed on the same position. Nothing special about that text. Something I noticed is that is seems to work when I put the last coordinate to 0 instead of 302. Only I don't fully understand the logic behind that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the wrong value in the fifth argument of `SetSimpleColumn` (and also in the third but that is not quite as wrong):

```
ct.SetSimpleColumn(myText, dLeftSide, dBottom + dFontLine, dLeftSide + dCellSize, dCellSize, 0, Element.ALIGN_CENTER)
```

As you see you always use `dCellSize` there, probably assuming that argument to be the height of the area, but the method is defined as:

```
/**
 * Simplified method for rectangular columns.
 * @param phrase a <CODE>Phrase</CODE>
 * @param llx the lower left x corner
 * @param lly the lower left y corner
 * @param urx the upper right x corner
 * @param ury the upper right y corner
 * @param leading the leading
 * @param alignment the column alignment
 */
virtual public void SetSimpleColumn(Phrase phrase, float llx, float lly, float urx, float ury, float leading, int alignment)
```

I.e. the fifth parameter should have been the upper **y** coordinate of the area (obviously not a constant).

Effectively your "upper **y**" for the first lines actually denoted the bottom **y** and your "lower **y**" the top **y**. With the "correction" by adding `dFontLine` that created the desired results.

As soon as your "lower **y**" actually started denoting the bottom **y**, the top **y** remained constant, so all entries from there on were printed at the same height.

This also explains your observation from a comment:

> Something I noticed is that is seems to work when I put the last coordinate to 0 instead of 302.

That way your "upper **y**" remains the bottom of the page. Thus, "upper" and "lower" remain switched but consistently so.

I assume you want something along this line:

```
ct.SetSimpleColumn(myText, dLeftSide, dBottom, dLeftSide + dCellSize, dBottom + dCellHeight, 0, Element.ALIGN_CENTER)
```

Comment: This seems to do the trick:

ct.SetSimpleColumn(myText, dLeftSide, dBottom + dFontLine, dLeftSide + dCellSize, dBottom - dCellHeight, 0, Element.ALIGN_CENTER)

Thanks!

Comment: @WiVM Well, that combination of parameters actually uses top and bottom **y** in a reversed order but this is something iText corrects internally; and if for some reason you happen to have a cell content too long for one line, you will get a second line which will overlap your cell borders. If that is no issue for you, use these parameters.